# Riley number four knows where you live

Tags: riddle, word

Here is my fourth Riley riddle! Hope you like it!

> My prefix is an annoying message which you seen many of,
>
> My suffix is worn at a fancy place,
>
> My infix is a famous doctor,
>
> And altogether you need me to find things.

Hint:

> The famous doctor doesn't actually doctor people.

Comment: That hint has to mean that the infix is Rot13(npghnyyl ersreevat gb Qe Qer); otherwise, I've got no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are an

> Address

My prefix is an annoying message which you seen many of,

> Ad.

My suffix is worn at a fancy place,

> Dress.

My infix is a famous doctor,

> Dre (he is not a real doctor).

And altogether you need me to find things.

> You need an address to go somewhere.